# Catching 404 and redirect to wwwroot

Tags: angular, docker, .net-core

I have an angular app hosted in my wwwroot folder of my API.

So if I start the container now with localhost:5000 all is fine and my Angular 2 App in my wwwwroot folder opens.

But if I do localhost:5000/asdasdasd which is no route of my API because the routes begin with localhost:5000/api/getbla, I get 404.

To prevent this I found this post:
https://github.com/aspnet/StaticFiles/issues/115#issuecomment-190499717

But it is also not working with docker build.

If I test it over IISExpress it is working.

Comment: just wanted to clarify, is your Angular managing the routes?

Comment: the .net core api is managing primary

Comment: I see, I thought Angular is managing your routes, I don't have any idea with .net api. sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Startup.cs add `UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects` and set your redirect, optionally you can set to pass error code as well if you want to show different error pages for different error codes.

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
 {
      // ...
      app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/#angularpage");
      // Or you can add placeholder for error code as well
      // app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/#angularpage?error={0}");
      // ...
 }
```

I think once you add '#' in your URL the request is handled by Angular.

Comment: didnt helped me , still 404

Comment: What is the full URL you want to redirect to?

Comment: i dont use hash strategy sry, i dont want to use it